# save the outputs from print statement in a data.frame in R

Tags: r

Is it possible to save outputs from "print" statements  as a data.frame in R? The example code is:

```
for (i in 1:3){
  print(paste(i,i+1,i+2))
}
```

Then I want to store the numbers in the red circle into a clean 3x3 data.frame. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print isn't necessary.

```
x <- 1:3
y <- x + 1
z <- y + 1

data <- data.frame(x,y,z)
data
```

...and the output:

```
> data
  x y z
1 1 2 3
2 2 3 4
3 3 4 5
>
```

### Saving results of `print()` to a vector

The results of a series of `print()` functions can be saved to a vector as follows.

```
x <- 1:3
printouts <- unlist(lapply(x,function(i) print(paste(i,i+1,i+2))))
printouts
```

...and the output:

```
> printouts
[1] "1 2 3" "2 3 4" "3 4 5"
>
```

### Converting the vector to a data frame

We can take the vector and convert to a data frame by reading with `read.csv()`. First, we'll edit the print a bit so it separates the data with commas rather than spaces. Then we'll generate the printouts and read into a data frame.

```
x <- 1:3
# use comma so we can parse with read.csv
printouts <- unlist(lapply(x,function(i) print(paste(i,i+1,i+2,sep=","))))
diagnostics <- read.csv(text = printouts,header = FALSE)
diagnostics
```

...and the output:

```
> diagnostics
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  2  3  4
3  3  4  5
>
```

Note that more useful column names can be set by using the `col.names=` argument in `read.csv()`.

### A reproducible example using multiple input files

Based on comments to my answer, here is a reproducible example that reads data from the [Pokémon Stats](https://github.com/lgreski/pokemonData) database, where we've separated the Pokémon into files by generation (1 - 7).

We'll read the data and write out to a log file any Pokémon whose Attack stats are greater than 120. First, we have code to download the zip file from my GitHub site if it hasn't already been downloaded.

```
if(!dir.exists("./pokemonData")){
     # download and unzip 
     download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/pokemonData.zip",
                   "pokemonData.zip",
                   mode="wb")
     unzip("pokemonData.zip")
}
```

Next, we'll set up a log file, including overwriting any prior copies so we can use `cat()` with `append=TRUE` as we write to the log file.

```
logFile <- "./pokemonData/highAttackStat.log"
# erase file in case it already exists, because we'll cat() with append mode
if (file.exists(logFile)) file.remove(logFile)
```

Next, we'll read the files and write to the log any observations where the Attack stat is greater than 120.

```
# read files and write to log any obs with 

thePokemonFiles <- list.files("./pokemonData",
                              full.names=TRUE)

dataList <- lapply(thePokemonFiles,function(x) {
     # read data 
     data <- read.csv(x)
     # write data for Pokemon with Attack > 120
     subset <- data[data$Attack > 120,]
     for(i in 1:nrow(subset)){
          if(subset[i,"Attack"] > 120){
               cat(paste(x,subset[i,"Number"],subset[i,"Name"],subset[i,"Attack"],sep=","),
                   file=logFile,sep="\n",append=TRUE)
          }
     }
})
```

Finally, we create a data frame from the log file via `read.csv()`.

```
# at this point we can read logfile w/ read.csv
theSubset <- read.csv(logFile,header = FALSE,col.names = c("File","Number","Name","Attack"))
head(theSubset)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(theSubset)
                     File Number                      Name Attack
1 ./pokemonData/gen01.csv      6 CharizardMega Charizard X    130
2 ./pokemonData/gen01.csv     15     BeedrillMega Beedrill    150
3 ./pokemonData/gen01.csv     68                   Machamp    130
4 ./pokemonData/gen01.csv     99                   Kingler    130
5 ./pokemonData/gen01.csv    112                    Rhydon    130
6 ./pokemonData/gen01.csv    115 KangaskhanMega Kangaskhan    125
>
```

Comment: My question above is a simplified example of my problem in real work. I need to loop over a large number of datasets, and some of them have issues. I need to identify which have issues, then print them, using sth like "print(file_number,column_number,the_issue)". And store the results. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, in that situation there are a number of ways to write content to a file within a loop or `apply()` function. I'll post some example code to do this .

Comment: @Jeremy - See my updated answer, which illustrates how to write print results to a vector, then convert the vector to a data frame with `read.csv()`.

Comment: @Jeremy - updated version includes code to write to log file via `cat()`.